# iOS11 screen capture changes

Tags: ios, screen, nativescript, capture

I had my screen capture code working fine till I moved to iOS11. I am assuming there are changes in their API (but I couldn't find anything/anywhere). Here's my (Nativescript) code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.ios.frame.size, false, 0);
view.ios.drawViewHierarchyInRectAfterScreenUpdates(CGRectMake(0, 0, view.ios.frame.size.width, view.ios.frame.size.height), true);
var imageFromCurrentImageContext = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageSource.fromData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageFromCurrentImageContext));
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?

Comment: It crashes the app because the image returns NULL. `Sep 20 14:00:43 Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2AFE44F6-8554-4CDF-884D-DA2FA2A10EEA[64058] (UIKitApplication:com.asouza.ppgFinder[0x6576][64084][74027]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]`